# How do I project confidence in communications at work?

Tags: work-environment

I work in a start-up IT company and we are introducing new a technology which I am responsible for. I am technically very good in this technology and do my work very seriously, but I am an introvert and reserved person and don't talk much. It's been 8 months and we are still finding some business use-cases for this new technology.

My boss has asked me to be more proactive and lead this or else he will fire me regardless of how good I am technically. I can't afford to lose this job and my boss is also right because no one else in the company has worked in this technology.

How can I project more confidence in my communications at work?

Comment: Being more proactive and less anxious is possibly more of an intrapersonal issue- something within yourself that you would like to improve.  Do you think it would help you to ask a question about the external aspects of your problem, perhaps "How do I project confidence in communications at work?" or "How can I strongly advocate for new ideas without seeming pushy?"

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: When you say that your boss wants you to be "more proactive and lead this" what is he looking for?  Does he want you to define products or services based on this new technology that your company can sell?